# Get distinct value from Union

Tags: mysql, distinct, union

Scenario:

```
Table A
MAPPING_ID    USER_TYPE    MODIFIED_ON
--------------------------------------

Table B
MAPPING_ID    ITEM_TYPE    MODIFIED_ON
--------------------------------------
```

I want to fetch the modified records[`MAPPING_ID`] in last one minute

```
(SELECT mapping_id FROM A WHERE modified_on > date_sub(now(),interval 1 minute) 
UNION 
(SELECT mapping_id from B WHERE modified_on > date_sub(now(),interval 1 minute)
```

But the problem is, which might have duplicated mapping_id in the result! How do I get `distinct` mapping_id on `UNION`?

Comment: Your query is already guaranteed to return a distinct set of `mapping_id`. There won't be an duplicated `mapping_id` returned by your query. (To get  the query to produce duplicates, you would have to replace the `UNION` set operator with the `UNION ALL` set operator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION removes duplicate rows by default, unless you use UNION ALL see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

If you want to do it manually though:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
(SELECT mapping_id FROM A WHERE modified_on > date_sub(now(),interval 1 minute) 
UNION 
(SELECT mapping_id from B WHERE modified_on > date_sub(now(),interval 1 minute) 
) subsub
```